# array not working in PHP

Tags: php, magento

Previously in PHP 5.4 I have create a payment redirection module. The bank ask me for security reasons to calculate the value $digest. Here is the code:

```
$form_data = "";
$form_data_array = array();

$form_data_array[1] = $merchantID;
$form_data_array[2] = $lang_fixed;
$form_data_array[3] = $orderId;
$form_data_array[4] = $order_descr_fixed;
$form_data_array[5] = $price_fixed;
$form_data_array[6] = $crncy;
$form_data_array[7] = $customerEmail;
$form_data_array[8] = $trans_type;
$form_data_array[9] = $form_confirmUrl;
$form_data_array[10] = $form_cancelUrl;
$form_data_array[11] = $sharedSecretKey;

$form_data = implode("", $form_data_array);
$digest = base64_encode(sha1($form_data,true));
```

This working fine with PHP 5.4. But when I choose PHP 5.6 the `$digest` is not calculated.

Comment: Try: `$digest = base64_encode(sha1($form_data));` to see if it's working.

Comment: No, nothing change

Comment: Update your post with the result of for `var_dump($form_data);` `var_dump(sha1($form_data))` and `var_dump($digest)` so we can find the error better.

Comment: Both `var_dump($form_data);` and `var_dump($digest)` returns NULL

Comment: So the problem it's there somewhere. Usualy implode returns null if second parameter is string. Can you `var_dump($form_data_array);` to make sure it's an array as expected.

Comment: Also `var_dump($form_data_array);` returns NULL

Comment: If everything is NULL the problem is somewhere when creating the array. I don't see what it's wrong, but you should check there.